# Insert max+1 based on group of data in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have table1 like below

```
1 Data1 type1 price1
2 Data2 type1 price2
3 Data3 type2 price3
4 Data4 type2 price4
```

the first column 1,2,3,4 are non identity (manually increment)

I want to inset in another table2

```
Table1(max+1)  Data1 type1 price1
Table1(max+1)  Data2 type1 price2
 Table1(max+1)  Data3 type2 price3
Table1(max+1)  Data4 type2 price4
```

result should be like this, based on type1,type2 ,it should increment.

```
5  Data1 Apple price1
5  Data2 Apple price2
6  Data3 Orange price3
6  Data4 Orange price4
```

Comment: Where are the numeric values associated with types 'Apple' and 'Orange'?

Comment: no its just example i have used type1, type2, it can be any string

Comment: But you want your `INT` to increment based somehow on your `type` field. You need to describe the relationship between those two values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with window functions:

```
select
    max(id) over() + dense_rank() over(order by type) as id,
    data,
    type,
    price   
from table
```

`max(id) over()` this will give you max value of id.

`dense_rank() over(order by type)` this will rank rows with same value for same types starting from 1.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go...

```
SELECT
    CAST(SUBSTRING(t1.Type, 5, 100) AS INT) + 4,
        /* In place of 4, use whatever base value you want */
    t1.Data,
    t1.Type,
    t1.Price    
FROM TestTable1 t1;
```

Output:

```
|   |  Data |  Type |  Price |
|---|-------|-------|--------|
| 5 | Data1 | type1 | price1 |
| 5 | Data2 | type1 | price2 |
| 6 | Data3 | type2 | price3 |
| 6 | Data4 | type2 | price4 |
```

[SQL Fiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e9d6f/1)

Comment: If we insert like this , your query got  error  --INSERT INTO TestTable1
SELECT 1, 'Data1','Apple','price1' UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'Data2','Apple','price2' UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'Data3','Orange','price3' UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'Data4','orange','price4';

Comment: @Venkat click the SQL Fiddle link.

Comment: i used the same link,Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'e' to data type int. Type1, Type2 will be any text like APPLE, Orange

Comment: @Venkat Ahhh, that would be good information to have in the original question. Can you update that please?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76694/discussion-between-venkat-and-phil-walton).